# strtotime returns today's date for a date in wrong format

Tags: php, datetime

When I pass '7.12.60' to strtotime, it returns timestamp of today! I know strtotime guesses the format of the given string but here the value is not correct at all! it just returns today's timestamp:

```
echo date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime('7.12.60') ); // outputs 2022-01-05!
```

What i expect is to receive a false or a correct value and not a made up one

Comment: `var_dump(strtotime('7.12.60'))`

Comment: @tkausl it is int(1641355980)

Comment: The 60 is probably confusing it, expecting a 4 digit year. If you use 1960, it works fine. `Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at the separator between the various components: if the separator is a slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format is assumed. If, however, the year is given in a two digit format and the separator is a dash (-), the date string is parsed as y-m-d.`

Comment: Is that supposed to be `7th Dec 1960` OR `12th July 1960`

Comment: @aynber yes I read it, it is not an European formar, so it should fail. Why it is returning today's timestamp?!!

Comment: Because it's converting it to a time, instead of a date. Try `Y-m-d H:i:s`, and you get `"2022-01-05 07:13:00"` -- 7th hour, 12th minute plus 60 seconds becomes the 13th minute

Comment: @RiggsFolly I would expect a false value or either of values you mentioned but it is returning today's timestamp

Comment: @user335870 It's treating it as a time without a date. In that case, the date is assumed to be today.

Comment: In other words, it's acting as if the value were `7:12:60`

Comment: Next issue, even if you change the `.` to `-` and use `DateTime` and `createFromFormat()` the 60 is going to be assumed to be 2060 rather than 1960, so to be sure you may also have to add a century to your dates if you are getting them in this format [DEMO](https://3v4l.org/9QGqT)

Comment: if  you replace . with - then it will return 0 or false or return into 01-01-1970

Comment: @RiggsFolly I added ' 00:00:00' and the problem get solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in comments of @aynber and others. It was considering it as a time and not a date, I added a time (00:00:00) to the end of the string and now it is returning false.

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: You can also replace the dot with dash and it will return invalid date

Answer (score 0):

The spelling of your date is not clear. What should '7.12.60' represent? 2060/12/07 or 1960/12/07 or 1860/12/07? You have to deliver the year number in 4 digits so that strtotime recognizes it correctly.

date_create_from_format() does not offer a solution here either, because for 'y', the two-digit representation of a year, it is assumed that it lies in the range from 1970 up to and including 2069.

If you need a different interval for the interpretation of two-digit year numbers, you have to redefine this and modify the input accordingly.